# looking for a way to test multiple tables across 2 oracle databases

Tags: python, oracle, toad

I am looking for help w/ a possible script to run where I can test a attribute on 2 different tables that have the same name, but are on different databases. we have a development DB and a production DB.  both have the same tables on them in the same schema on that particular table.

For example `devdb` has a table called `data.abc_001`.  `proddb` also has a table called `data.abc_001`.  What I want to do is to find differences between the two on a attribute called '`updated`'. The other issue is, due to our data structure, we have `data.abc_001` through `data.abc_999`.  I think the best outcome would be to have a table with 2 columns (one from each db, with a value of 'updated' where they are different).  I am using Toad to interact w/ the DBs.

Comment: What do you mean by "testing an attribute on 2 tables" and "find the differences on an attribute"... ? What exactly do you need to find? Either use precise technical language (which "testing an attribute on two tables" and "find the differences on an attribute" are **not**), or use common language but describe what you need in full details.

Comment: Database Links... have you tried exploring the idea of using Database Links?

Answer (score 0):

If the servers can reach each other, I think the easiest thing is to do something like this from the prod server:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK "DEV"
CONNECT TO data
IDENTIFIED BY "my_password"
USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
  (Host=dev_server)
  (PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DEV)))';

create table abc_001_differences as
select a.updated as prod_updated, b.updated as dev_updated
  from abc_001 a
  full outer join abc_001@"DEV" b on a.primary_key = b.primary_key
;
```

Another option you might consider is this TOAD feature: open the Database menu and go to Compare > Single Object. Pick your connections/schema/table, and just go through the options. If you prefer a GUI, it's a powerful tool.